# Using And Clause in Laravel Query Bulider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT
  customers.CustCompanyName,
  addresses.AddressLine1,
  orders.*
FROM orders
  INNER JOIN customers
    ON orders.CustID = customers.CustID
  INNER JOIN customer_addresses
    ON customer_addresses.CustID = customers.CustID
  INNER JOIN addresses
    ON customer_addresses.AddressID = addresses.AddressID
    AND orders.CustAddID = customer_addresses.CustAd
```

How do I incorporate the AND clause in using laravel Query Builder:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->join('customers', 'orders.CustID', '=', 'customers.CustID')
        ->join('customer_addresses','customer_addresses.CustID', '=' , 'customers.CustID' )
        ->join('addresses','customer_addresses.AddressID','=','addresses.AddressID')->AND
```

I can't find any working examples using the AND clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For:

```
INNER JOIN addresses
   ON customer_addresses.AddressID = addresses.AddressID
   AND orders.CustAddID = customer_addresses.CustAd
```

you should use:

```
->join('addresses', function($join) {
   $join->on('customer_addresses.AddressID', '=', 'addresses.AddressID')
   ->whereRaw('orders.CustAddID = customer_addresses.CustAd');
});
```

You can also look at [Joins in Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) for details